# magento 2.4 category_form.xml add comment to fields

Tags: magento2.4, adminform, category-attribute

I'm creating some custom fields for my categories, so I've added a couple of simple text fields in the database with the setup php script, then extended the `category_form.xml` to show my fields in the admin category page. Everything works fine: I see the fields in the admin category page and I can save the values.

I'd like to add a line of comments under those fields. I thought I could just use the `comment` tag like I do in every other xml form but here I get the error "Element 'comment' is not expected".

Is there a way to add a comment-like sentence under the field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a note field in the `eav_attribute` table. This field is used to store the label that appears below the fields in the admin screen.

As a consequence, you can add a `data patch` that updates the category attribute you have created so that the `note`'s value for this attribute has the label you want to set.

Below is an example for product at `\Magento\Catalog\Setup\Patch\Data\UpdateProductMetaDescription`. I did try manually for category and it works indeed.

```
/** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);

        $eavSetup->updateAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'meta_description',
            [
                'note' => 'Maximum 255 chars. Meta Description should optimally be between 150-160 characters'
            ]
        );
```